# MethodNotAllwedException 405 Laraval 5.5.*

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've defined several API routes in my Laravel application's api.php file using the POST method. However, when I attempt to call these routes from Postman, the application throws the following error:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException:
> in file
> /home/my-repo/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php
> on line 255

**Route**

Route::post('login', 'ApiController@login');
Above route I call from postman with post method but I get error all the time.

Note: I have deployed my code on sharedhosting "namecheap"

Answer (score 0):

I might guess based on provided information that you have issue with your request uri in postman.
Make sure that:

- your uri pointing at exact route defined in your api.php. for exmaple: http://base.url/api/login
- your request is defined as POST http method.
- check for syntax error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65825666/laravel-rest-apis-working-in-reqbin-com-but-not-in-postman-also-not-working-in-t/65826009#65826009 related to this one.

Answer (score -2):

- The problem from the CSRF TOKEN which is being checked on each request.
- Except the route in `Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`

  protected $except = [
  '/example',
  '/api/example'
  ];

Comment: I also added this "'api.php/*',"api/*" in 'Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken' but still same issue

Comment: route is written in route/api.php file