# Laravel Rest Apis working in reqbin.com but not in postman also not working in the app

Tags: laravel, api, rest

Here is a screenshot from the postman
[Post Man Call Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLckM.png)

Screenshot from reqbin.com

It showing the following exception on the postman!

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException:  in file /home/elitbzfn/ecoplus.work/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php on line 255
```

[Reqbin Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUXds.png)

Please tell me what could be the issue here possibly! Thanks

If you anything fee free to ask me! Thanks

Headers

[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoFDh.png)

Comment: what are these headers you are sending?

Comment: I have added the header screenshot at the end! Please check! Thanks

Comment: that does not show them, since they are hidden

Comment: Actually, I am new to laravel! Can you please tell me how I can see the headers? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with **https** and not with **http**. This might be an issue.

Comment: Yeah, http definietly causing the trouble. Just checked it on my machine. That's because your project configured to handle requests only from secured connections.

Comment: Yes, the issue was in HTTP. I changed it to HTTPS and it is solved! Thanks a lot! May God bless you!